# Javascript Regular Expression Split with Grouping

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following string:

```
&bull; This is string 1<br />&bull; This is string 2<br />&bull; This is string 3<br />
```

How can I get all of the content between the `&bull;` and `<br />` so I end up w/:

```
["This is string 1", "This is string 2", "This is string 3"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s.replace(/(^&bull;\s*|<br(?: ?\/)?>)/g, "").split(/&bull;\s*/g);
```

Simple but effective, assuming the string is consistently delimited by "&bull;<br />" sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) (*since js won't support lookbehind assertion*).

```
&bull;\s*(.*?)(?=<br\s*\/>)
```

`(?=<br\s*\/>)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by `<br>` string. `\s*` matches zero or more space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/8)

Get the desired string from group index 1.

```
> var s = []
undefined
> var f = "&bull; This is string 1<br />&bull; This is string 2<br />&bull; This is string 3<br />"
undefined
> var re = /&bull;\s*(.*?)(?=<br\s*\/>)/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(f)) != null) {
... s.push(m[1]);
... }
3
> console.log(s)
[ 'This is string 1', 'This is string 2', 'This is string 3' ]
```

Comment: replace `(.*?)` in the above regex with `([\s\S]*?)` , if the input contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
&bull;\s*(.*?)<br\s*\/>
```

You can do it simply by `capturing` the required groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/23

```
var re = /&bull;\s*(.*?)<br\s*\/>/gi;
var str = '&bull; This is string 1<br />&bull; This is string 2<br />&bull; This is string 3<br />';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
var a='&bull; This is string 1<br />&bull; This is string 2<br />&bull; This is string 3<br />';
var r=a.split(/&bull;\s*|<br\s*\/>/);
var nr=r.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
console.log(nr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```